# Load inserted Items only in Listview using SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sqldatasource

I have a SqlDataSource which helps a Listview to Insert/Delete new data. But, I don't want to show the existing data to the Listview using this SqlDataSource. Only the newly inserted records to be shown. But, this shows everything on the Listview. If I remove the SelectCommand, Even the newly inserted rows won't be shown.

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorSOAPaymentsInnerDS" runat="server"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
      InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO VendorSOAPayments ( VendorSOAID, PaymentVoucherID, PaymentAmount) VALUES( @VendorSOAID, @PaymentVoucherID, @PaymentAmount)"  
      SelectCommand= "SELECT A.VendorSOAPaymentID, A.PaymentVoucherID, B.SubProjectID, B.StatementBreakDown, A.PaymentAmount, C.SubProjectCode, C.SubProjectName FROM  VendorSOAPayments A INNER JOIN VendorSOA B ON A.VendorSOAID = B.VendorSOAID INNER JOIN SubProject C ON B.SubProjectID = C.SubProjectID WHERE A.PaymentVoucherID  = @PaymentVoucherID  AND B.Vendor_EntityID = @VendorID "
     DeleteCommand = "DELETE VendorSOAPayments WHERE VendorSOAPaymentID = @VendorSOAPaymentID" >
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListPayVoucherID" Name="PaymentVoucherID" PropertyName="Value" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="vendorSelectID" Name="VendorID" PropertyName="Value" /> 
      </SelectParameters>
      <InsertParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="VendorSOAID" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="PaymentAmount" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListPayVoucherID" Name="PaymentVoucherID" PropertyName="Value" />
       </InsertParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add inserted records to a `datatable` and save the `datatable` to a session.